# CREATE VIEW inside a PROCEDURE in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Basically I want create a view that depends on a input.

This code compile without problems

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_photo_city (input COUNTRY.City%TYPE)
IS
command VARCHAR2(2000) := 'CREATE VIEW view_photo_city AS SELECT IDPhoto FROM COUNTRY WHERE Country.City = input';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command;
END;
/
```

but when I call the procedure:

```
CALL pr_photo_city ('Rome');
```

it says:

```
ORA-00904: "INPUT": invalid identifier
```

for those who are wondering that input is a key-word i tested changing it, so the problem is not that

Comment: Taking a step back, why would you want to do this?  Creating objects at runtime is almost never a good idea in Oracle.   Once you get it to work, the second call will fail since the view already exists.  If you change to `create or replace` to fix that, now one session might end up replacing the view before the first session can do something with it.  It seems much more likely that you want to create a view that has a predicate based on a context value that you can set or that you want to create a pipelined table function you can pass a parameter into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to concatenate that value (as you can't use bind variable with DDL); beware of SQL injection.

On the other hand, in Oracle it is **rarely** good idea to dynamically create objects from within PL/SQL. Think twice whether you want to do that.

---

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from luogo;

    IDFOTO CITTA
---------- ------
         1 London
         2 Berlin
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_foto_citta (input LUOGO.Citta%TYPE)
  2  IS
  3    comando VARCHAR2(2000);
  4  BEGIN
  5    comando := 'CREATE VIEW vista_foto_citta AS
  6      SELECT IDFoto FROM LUOGO WHERE LUOGO.Citta = ' ||
  7      dbms_assert.enquote_literal(input);
  8
  9      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE comando;
 10  END;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec pr_foto_citta('London');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From vista_foto_citta;

    IDFOTO
----------
         1

SQL>
```

---

Generally speaking, when working with dynamic SQL, it is good to **display** command you're going to insert - that helps with debugging. In your case, this is the output:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_foto_citta (input LUOGO.Citta%TYPE)
  2  IS
  3  command VARCHAR2(2000) := 'CREATE VIEW vista_foto_citta AS SELECT IDFoto FROM LUOGO WHERE LUOGO.Citta = input';
  4  BEGIN
  5    --  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command;
  6    dbms_output.put_line(command);
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec pr_foto_citta('London');
CREATE VIEW vista_foto_citta AS SELECT IDFoto FROM LUOGO WHERE LUOGO.Citta = input

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, what do you think? Can you successfully execute this:

```
CREATE VIEW vista_foto_citta AS SELECT IDFoto FROM LUOGO WHERE LUOGO.Citta = input
```

I don't think so; Oracle as well - that's why it complained about `input`.